# Git error: failed to push some refs

Tags: git

I think I did 'git pull' before being in a branch, and now when I do 'git branch' it shows this:

```
* (no branch)
  master
```

How can I move 'no branch' into 'master' so then I can do 'git push' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To move between branches:

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

To push the commits of a branch without being *in* it, you can specify more parameters after the `push` command:

```
git push <remote> <branch_name>
```

This will push the local branch that tracks the remote branch called `branch_name`.

Comment: But, if you would like to keep whatever you committed on the current branch (even if it is not referenced by a reference), do a `git branch my-no-branch-with-commits` first.

Comment: @fork0 When I did 'checkout' the '(no branch)' branch disappeared, but git told me to use the hash to create a new branch like fork0 said, something like 'git branch new_branch_name bc8adcb8da7bc8dabcd87a'. Then I just merged and push worked.